# Node-sass will not compile valid css

Tags: css, sass, node-sass

I get the following error when running node-sass on valid CSS.

```
SassError: Invalid CSS after "html {": expected "}", was "{"
        on line 9 of C:\Users\<user>\Documents\<project>\styles\index.sass
\>> html { {

   ------^
```

I cannot understand why.

Here is the sass file

```
@charset "utf-8";

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,600,700&display=swap');

$family-primary: "Poppins", sans-serif;

html {
  background-color: #212121;
}
```

Comment: Also in my experience, it's best practice not to import Google Fonts into compiled stylesheets. Instead, I always make a separate call to link that sheet in my HTML. @import is basically copying all their styles into your stylesheet which circumvents any dynamic runtime stuff Google might be doing.

Comment: You were correct. That solves the issue. Thank you!

Comment: Glad that helped! I'll create a full answer for anyone else who stumbles across this...

Answer (score 1):

I would guess the error stems from using `@import` to include a Google Fonts Stylesheet. There's likely a couple of things going on here.

1. When you use `@import` with SCSS you get one stylesheet *copied into* your primary styles. As this happens before the compile is complete any errors in the imported CSS will impact the compiler's ability to parse your valid CSS. In other words, your CSS is completely valid but you don't know what's in the imported CSS that might cause the final to break.
2. Specifically, in the case of Google Fonts, the resulting CSS is actually dynamically generated based on your browser's features. The goal is to provide only the needed font types and file payloads for a given browser. Since you're including Google's CSS into compiled CSS, Google doesn't know what to serve up to Node.js (not a browser) and may break.
3. Even if Google does guess how to send you CSS that will happily compile inside your SASS parser it won't contain all the font support for every browser, in turn, hampering your user experience.

---

### Solutions:

CSS files that contain `@import` make a new HTTP request at run time so you could go this route. To do so you need to exclude the import from the SASS parser. SASS doesn't have a great way to do this but you could try putting the whole line in quotes hopefully causing SASS to ignore it.

`"@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,600,700&display=swap');"`

Unfortunately, imported CSS like this is runtime render-blocking. So if the Google CSS can't load for some reason (like being blocked in China), it will cause your entire render process to stop until it times out. **All around not great.**

The best bet, in this case, is likely to add another CSS call in your HTML document. Yes, you get another request but this doesn't block the render (which is why you can get flashes of unstyled text) and significantly simplifies your setup.

```
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,600,700&display=swap">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mySiteStyles.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that was not the fix. It was an indentation issue when using the .sass extension. switching to .scss solved the problem.